# Is this a Tsetse fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, species, biological-control

I found this on my back while looking in the mirror.It took me 10 minutes to kill it.I hit it well at least 5 times before it died.It kept flying to me every time i tried to hit it,trying to go under my shorts

Is this a TseTse fly?

[image]

what fly is this?

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

This is a species of Hippobosca, looks like H. equina. There aren't too many species of this genus, so the species may be this one, which is rather common in Europe, Africa and parts of Asia - see https://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/Hippobosca-equina-Linnaeus-1758-img485046.html. Since you suggested it could be a tsetse fly, I assume you are in Africa. Hippobosca equina occurs in Africa as well. Other hippoboscids are not as strong fliers as Hippobosca species, which would explain its flying back to you over and over.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve.I am actually from Greece.The title was for click-bait and the suspense :P ! The smartest fly i have ever seen.